# How to see “rails s” from other ip or ssid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cloud9

I wanna see the local web development built by rails from other ip.
I mean when I run “rails s” I can see web which I built.
And I wanna share it to my friend.
And I know I can see the same page from other devise if it is connected to the same wifi.
But how I can see local developing web from far away like other wifi.
I don’t think it’s impossible.
Because in aws cloud9, I can see the preview, even ec2 is not local server.
How does it work?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a tool called [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/). So you start your local server, like you're currently doing `rails s`, then in a second tab you can run `./ngrok http 3000`. It will provide you both an http and https url which can be accessed.

Comment: Wow that’s exactly what I wanted to know. 
Thank you very much!!